# C++ floating point numbers incorrect output

Tags: c++, macos, types, floating-point, output

So, I'm new to C++ and I have come across a weird behavior. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    float fValue = 123.12;
    cout << fixed << "Value: " << fValue << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output is kind of weird.

For different fValues the output is different e.g:

fValue: 123.12   Output: 123.120003

fValue: 1234.12   Output: 1234.119995

fValue: 1234.1231   Output: 1234.123047

So, not sure what I'm doing wrong here or what the problem is.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Looks like a very in-depth explanation and I'll be taking a look at it soon as I can.

Comment: @CoryKramer Regarding your response, I get it. It happens, it's how things work. But how does one prevent these things from actually messing up your program. Tolerance value sounds a bit hard for a new programmer to actually figure it out. So, is there a short term solution to actually calculate with full precision?

Comment: @c0mp13x computers have limited precision. If you want better precision than what a `float` offers, use a `double`. It's still limited to a certain number of bits - but it's more precise than a `float`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see. Thanks, I'll try to see which can be implemented better, based on what I am working.

Comment: @c0mp13x If the precision of a `double` isn't good enough, you may try `long double`. If that's not enough you'll need some external BigNum library.

Comment: Note that on Visual Studio`long double` is the same as `double`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Got it. Didn't know those libraries existed, nice to know but I don't think I'll be ever using them for the near future.

Comment: @drescherjm I am using VS Code for macOS and sizeof does not agree with that statement here :)
I'll be sure to check it out on a Windows platform.

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant Visual Studio (using the Microsoft compiler) not Visual Studio Code. I guess I should have paid more attention to the tags.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, no problem man!